# How to export angular 6 grid data to excel?

Tags: angular6

want to export angular 6 grid data to ms excel file on client side

I have tried using web api using mvc 5 but problem is that not able to sent data from datatable i.e server side to client side for export

C# Code to export data to excel but unable to send datatable data at client side to export it in excel file

```
                   if (callrec != null)
                 {
                      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[7] {
                    new DataColumn("RECORDING FILE NAME",typeof(string)),
                    new DataColumn("ACCOUNT NUMBER",typeof(string)),
                    new DataColumn("CALL START TIME",typeof(string)),
                    new DataColumn("AGENT NAME",typeof(string)),
                    new DataColumn("AGENT RESULT",typeof(string)),
                    new DataColumn("DURATION SECONDS",typeof(string)),
                    new DataColumn("PHONE DIALED",typeof(string))
                });

                foreach (var item in callrec)
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add(item.RecFileName,
                       item.AccountNo == "NULL" ? "" : item.AccountNo,
                       item.CallStartTime == null ? null : 
                 item.CallStartTime,
                       item.agentName == "NULL" ? "" : item.agentName,
                       item.agentResults == "NULL" ? "" : 
                   item.agentResults,
                       item.DurationSecs,
                       item.phoneDialed == "NULL" ? "" : item.phoneDialed);
                };

                using (ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook wb = new 
                  ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook())
                {
                    var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(dt, "CallRecording");
                    ws.Tables.FirstOrDefault().ShowAutoFilter = false;

                    MemoryStream stream = GetStream(wb);
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control- 
                Allow-Origin", "*");
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control- 
                    Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content- 
                    Type, Accept");
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content- 
                   disposition", "attachment; filename= 
                 CallRecording.xlsx");
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = 
                    "application/vnd.ms-excel";


              HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(stream.ToArray());
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
                }
            }
            else if(callrec==null || callrec.Count==0)
            {
                throw new Exception("Null or empty input table to 
                 export!");
            }
        }
```

Export data to client side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   Finally Got Solution on my Question export at client side Using Angular 6




 const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = 
 XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(this.callRecordingModels);
 /* generate workbook and add the worksheet */
 const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
  XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, worksheet, 'Sheet1');
 /* save to file */
  XLSX.writeFile(wb, this.fileName);
```